# Python xlwings - Issue when copying worksheet with PivotTable

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlwings

I am working with a workbook with the sheets (Data & Pivot). Pivot sheet contains a Pivot table with data source from Data sheet.

We're using xlwings to write data to a new workbook with worksheet as Data. As a second step, I want to copy the Pivot Table as the second worksheet that references data in the new worksheet. However, when I copy it over, it keeps the data source as `[Workbook1.xlsx]Data'!$A:$Y`

I'd like to be copied over with data range as `Data!$A:$Y` as in the original source workbook.

Using below code to copy the worksheet:

`source_wb.sheets['Pivot'].copy(after=new_wb.sheets['Data'], name='Pivot')`

One of the reason I don't want to add an additional step to correct the data source range is because worksheets may or may not contain pivots. I have read documentations for xlwings and open items if any, but no luck yet.